# safari mobile scroll lost when height is resized

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have an iframe in my website page. When i view it on safari mobile, if the height of the iframe content is resized (as an example, I click on a button that add some text at the end of the iframe content), the scrools is lost and the page is on the top again.

I checked all resize events and all event handlers in the page, but they are executed after scroll is lost. I checked all setintervall too, but they are not the cause.

This bug occurs only in safari mobile and chrome ios, not android nor any desktop browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem with this code css (I already tried `-webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;` but it was not enough, I had to add `overflow` :

```
html,body{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```